# Building Link List for Custom Tax

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, custom-post-type-archives

Just wanted to get an opinion, or ideas. I have an CPT called "Listings", and a custom taxonomy for it called `directory-category`.

I have put together the below function to generate a list of links for the terms for the custom taxonomy.

I tried using `get_term_link()` and couldn't get it to generate the links properly.

This code is working and when called it generates the links to the archive of each tax term.
However, I am thinking there is a better way to accomplish this, any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

```
function ebx_listing_tax_links() {
    echo '<div class = "ebx-cat-bar">';
    $url = site_url();
    $cat = "/directory-category/";
    $terms = get_terms( 'listing_categories' );
    if($terms) : foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        ?><a class="ebx-cat-link" href="<?php
        echo $url;
        echo $cat;
        echo $term->slug;
        ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a><?php
    } endif;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that code - it may break a lot of things... Main question is: why `get_term_link` isn't working correctly? What's wrong with it? How do you use it? How is the taxonomy registered?

Comment: I agree, looked at it again this morning and changed it back to the get_term_link , I had a concatenation mistake with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work, i was concatenating the html incorrectly.

`$terms = get_terms( 'listing_categories' );
 if($terms) : foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
        } endif;`